# xdg-open opening wrong application

Tags: xdg-open

I do not know where to ask this.

When I type help, I get "help: Help is being displayed in xdg-open."
Which is normal I suppose, but the problem is it opens up in Todoist application, which is an AppImage application.

I have searched around and can't find a good starting point on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to find out the mimetype of the help file with `xdg-mime  query filetype helpfile` and then set the desired app with `xdg-mime default app.desktop mimetype`

Comment: Who would ever think in my case that text/html was a wrong direction of my troubleshooting because of another obscure type application/xhtml+xml interfering to type detection! Lo and behold:

"xdg-mime query filetype q.html" gives "application/xhtml+xml" while "file --mime-type q.html" gives "q.html: text/html"

WTF going on in this mime-world-tm?? I couldn't resolve this issue for few last years until hit on this comment above!

Answer (score 0):

As @Harry pointed out, first determine the mime type of the file in question:

1. `file --mime-type $somefile`

You can then check what sources a querried by `xdg-open` regarding the application to run the corresponding file type:

2. `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default $type`

If you're not happy with the default application for a type, you can override it:

3. (Optional) Edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

See the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list).